# Create object and child objects in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 Serializers, Order and OrderDetail:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    detail = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['pk', 'user', 'date', 'status', 'detail ']


    def create(self, validated_data):

        order= Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        detail_data = validated_data.pop('detail')

        if detail_data :
            for detail in detail_data :
                OrderDetail.objects.create(order=order, **detail)
        return order

    def get_detail(self, obj):
        """obj is an order instance. Return list of dicts"""
        queryset = OrderDetail.objects.filter(order= obj)
        return [OrderDetailSerializer(m).data for m in queryset]
```

and

```
class OrderDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Just in case if its needed for create for multiple instances """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
        super(OrderDetailSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

    order = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Order.objects.all())
    product = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Product.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = OrderDetail
        fields = ['pk', 'order', 'product', 'quantity','individual_price']
```

In postman I send:

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "date": "2020-06-02",
    "status": "Approved",
    "detail": [
        {
            "product": 2,
            "quantity": "3",
            "individual_price": "15.00"
        },
        {
            "product": 1,
            "quantity": "1",
            "individual_price": "10.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

And it throws the following error:

> KeyError at /api/v1/order/
>   'detail'

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/order/
Django Version: 3.0.3

When I print the data its showing this:

```
{'user': <User: test>, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 6, 3), 'status': 'Approved'}
```

Seems like detail its a  read only field, dont know if its for the SerializerMethodField.
About that, I need detail with SerializerMethodField to format the response like this:

```
results": [
        {
            "pk": 1,
            "user": 1,
            "date": "2020-06-03",
            "status": "Approved",
            "detail": [
                {
                    "pk": 2,
                    "order": 1,
                    "product": 2,
                    "quantity": "3",
                    "individual_price": "15.00"
                },
                {
                    "pk": 3,
                    "order": 1,
                    "product": 1,
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "individual_price": "10.00"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Also I use ListCreateAPIView in the views and the models have the same info as the fields in Serializers

```
class OrderList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
        Returns orders by user
    """
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Order.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Comment: Please check the docs of writable-nested-representations ref at [writable-nested-representations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)

Comment: What happens if you just use `detail = OrderDetailSerializer(many=True)` ?

Comment: @upendra243 you're right, thas what I need, checked documentation several times and didnt found it. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter as you say, thats part of the process, thank you!